# iTunes connect configuration for product logs

Tags: xcode4, in-app-purchase, mkstorekit

While testing my in-app-purchases, I am receiving these in my console for both attached devices and simulators. Can anyone suggest what might be wrong with my build? My app has been submitted to the store and is currently waiting for review.

Problem in iTunes connect configuration for product: com.mugunthkumar.subinapptest.wk1
Problem in iTunes connect configuration for product: com.mugunthkumar.caltasks.propack
Problem in iTunes connect configuration for product: com.mugunthkumar.inappsubtest.consumable1

While testing on devices, I also have seen this message. It may be related. I don't have entitlements checked on the summary. I did not set up the provisioning profiles, so I cannot say how the iCloud was configured on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your product bundle name in itunes connect `com.mugunthkumar.subinapptest` ? Also are your in-app purchases fully set up in itunes connect?

Is the plist in `MKStoreKit` correctly configured?

Comment: Thanks. I recently updated from GutHub and did not have the MKStoreKit plist configured.